# Unity3d 3D Text always displayed Blur

Tags: fonts, unity-game-engine

While similar questions have been posted before, but none actually suited my Case where Orthographic Camera is also involved, so culling logic would be different.

So, in my scene I have a orthographic camera and I want to display 3D text, after following the steps as per the official documentation : http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-TextMesh.html

My text is still blurred, while the one shown in the example seems perfect.

[image: The texts are 'Test123' and 'Text234' both from TTF font files]

Is it only supported for selected font types?

Are there any more references to fixing this problem?

Looking for all the help I can get to get this text displaying correctly.

Comment: Can you give an image of what it looks like and what it should look like?

Comment: I have updated the question with a snapshot , The texts are  'Test123' and 'Text234' both from TTF font files.

Comment: The documentation notes that you should use *GUI Text* if you need them in 2D.

Comment: I need them as 3D- says the heading of my post too

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A blur text is usually caused by a too high scale of the `3DText` `GameObject`.

Try to **reduce the scale** of your `GameObject` and **increase the font size** instead.

Comment: Awesome that did the trick, but I had to scale down to 0.1 and 0.2 on X-Y axis, any way, I could have got this without scaling it down so low.

Comment: @rock_win: what's your font size and the distance from the camera?

Comment: Interestingly after seeing some similar post like my case, I had set the font size to be 80 and the distance to camera is 15units

Comment: @rock_win: I've tried 80 fs and 15U distance with arial font and it looks fine. Maybe it depends on your font. Btw 3DText isn't the best, it has some problems on lighting too.

Comment: just to add the size 80 was in the font material-texture- the asset one, the rendered font i have made it to 0 to be the default assuming it renders as good as possible... i keep rotating the objects, so my normal 2d text just keep flying around instead of rating at a center point